# Warnings in CouchDB after connecting Logstash to _changes feed

Tags: logstash, couchdb, logstash-configuration

I'm using [Logstashs Couchdb_changes input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-couchdb_changes.html#plugins-inputs-couchdb_changes) to index data from CouchDB via Logstash into OpenSearch.

Everythings works but since Logstash is connected the following warning appears frequently in CouchDBs log:

> nonode@nohost <0.25763.501> 538e297d5b couch_db calculate_start_seq uuid prefix mismatch db: <<"shards/20000000-3fffffff/someDB.1632477056">>, seq: 11332, uuid: <<"68ddbfc">>, epoch_node: nonode@nohost

The configuration for Logstash to listen to _changes feed is simple:

```
couchdb_changes {
  db => "someDB"
  port => 5984
  host => "some_host"
  username => "foo"
  password => "bar"
  keep_id => true
  add_field => {"[doc][some_field]" => "some value"
}
```

The error message sounds like CouchDB start to calculating sequences ... but I wonder why Logstash is the cause.

Maybe somebody can help me in interpreting the error message?